# Clean way to write urls instead of concatenation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been finding myself doing URLs like this:

```
$link = base_url('post') . '/' . $post_id . '/' . $slug . '/page/' . $page_num;
```

To form http://example.com/post/10/some-post-name/page/1

Needless to say, it's pretty messy, but I can't think of an alternative? Is there a better way  write links with variables in it?

I am using Codeigniter as a framework if there is a solution involving it.

Comment: You could use double-quotes (`""`)?

Comment: Sprintf http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php is good

Comment: Double quotes look the best in my opinion, and are the fastest of all alternatives....only your code beats double quotes in speed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316060/single-quotes-or-double-quotes-for-variable-concatenation

Comment: heh - its actually easier to read then any of the posted alternatives - and its the fastest. but yes to using site_url(), that was a good catch -- and double quotes would read a little easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few ways:

First, via sprintf:

```
sprintf('%s/%s/%s/page/%s', base_url('post'), $post_id, $slug, $page_num);
```

Or via an array implode:

```
implode('/', array(base_url('post'), $post_id, $slug, 'page', $page_num));
```

Or if you put all your values into variables, you can take advantage of string interpolation.

```
$url = ...;
...
"$url/$post_id/$slug/page/$page_num";
```

The last one is longer when you take into account the variable assignment block, but it combines succintness with readability.

Comment: The last one is also undoubtedly the fastest. http://micro-optimization.com/string-concatenation-with-double-quotes-vs-sprintf

Answer (score 2):

Use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$link = sprintf('%s/%d/%s/page/%d', base_url('post'), $post_id, $slug, $page_num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$link = site_url("post/{$post_id}/{$slug}/page/{$page_num}");
```

You really should be using [`site_url()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) instead of `base_url()` for CI links. `base_url()` is meant for non-CI assets, like images and css.

`site_url()` will point to the correct front controller path, so you can update your configuration at will, and everything using that to build paths will update accordingly.

I revised my answer. Use the [curly brace notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) and avoid using extra functions. You can pass an array of arguments to the function, like so:

```
$link = site_url(array('post', $post_id, $slug, 'page', $page_num));
```

But working with arrays is slower. This can be useful if you need to dynamically build the url, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the old fashioned way with a function!

```
function buildlink($base_url,$post_id,$slug,$page_num)
{
  return $base_url . '/' . $post_id . '/' . $slug . '/page/' . $page_num;
}
```

call it like this

```
$link = buildlink(base_url('post') ,$post_id, $slug ,$page_num);
```

but maybe i'm missing something