# Using PHP variables dynamically in MySQL statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the query below.

```
$condition = "WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id'"; 
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM emp_table".$condition;
```

I expect my query to be like this, but dynamically:

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id'";
```

Is there anyway to make SQL statements dynamically through variables in php..?

Comment: what's the error you getting?

Comment: first, `myquery` is missing a `$`; second, it will read `... emp_tableWHERE ...`; third: what database library are you using? mysqli? PDO? What's your code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php < this might help

Comment: thanks for the replies but nothing turned out.. :(

Comment: Looks like there's not enough info in the question to solve the mystery. So, please elaborate...

Comment: Look at the expanded SQL string (`var_dump($myquery, __FILE__.__LINE__);`) and try it in an 'SQL IDE ' (phpmyadmin) is fine. It should work exactly the same there as in PHP. If it isn't clear what is happening then please post the complete code you are using to execute this SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$condition = "WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id'"; 
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM emp_table ".$condition;
```

you forgot to put $ on myquery

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? -

```
$condition = "WHERE emp_id = '" . $emp_id . "'"; 
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM emp_table " . $condition;
```

PHP does not expand variables within single-quote strings.

```
echo "$name"; //works

echo '$name'; //does not work
```

Take a look at this: [Single quotes or double quotes for variable concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316060/single-quotes-or-double-quotes-for-variable-concatenation)

Comment: Sterex, I tried but still its the same.. helpless :(

Comment: Where are you getting the error? And what is the error?

Comment: its not including the variables in SQL statement, i get error in $myquery,

Comment: Hey @Multi-Coder, although I hate linking to W3Schools, here's something that will help you get started with PHP/MySQL (looks like you are VERY new to this): http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_select.asp

Can you try using their syntax for preparing and executing your queries?

Comment: hi.. thanks for ur response.. :) .. i am not new and i knew what all were there.. my problem is different.. example : i need a query = "select * from table" .. but i am spliting is as two variables.. $var1= "Select * ", $var2 = "from query". and finally, i execute my query as $myquery = $var1.$var2;  .. But its not working

Answer (score 0):

You should never build queries dynamically like that. Correct way to do it is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

In your case it'll be like that

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE emp_id = :emp_id");
$statement->execute(array(
    ':emp_id' => $emp_id
));

$rows = $statements->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Hi elon, I dont need to include variable in WHICH clause.. My requirement is, depending on the input, the WHERE clause itself is to be included r excluded.. ex) if emp-id is blank, then it should not include the condition emp_id = $emp_id

Comment: You should include that in your question.

Comment: Sorry for that, but my example stated that.. may be you dnt have a look